# How to include Epson SDK for JavaScript in CommonJS project

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs, thermal-printer, epson

I have a project with WebPack, where modules are imported with CommonJS structure.

Now I need to import the `ePOS_SDK_JavaScript_v2.7.0` library (file "epos-2.7.0.js").
But it is not a valid CommonJS module.

How can I import the library in my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some hours I found a simplest solution.

1) **edit `epos-2.7.0.js` file**
Insert this row in top of file:

```
var io = module.exports;
```

2) **import the library**
The SDK is not pretty recognized by CommonJS, then it is required to declare the `epson` variable:

```
import '../<path>/epos-2.7.0.js';
declare var epson;
```

## For TypeScript projects

```
import '../<path>/epos-2.7.0.js';
declare var epson: any;
```